# check if a layout contains any ImageView or TextView android

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I want to know is there any way to check a parent layout's childs ?

with or without id ?

Comment: what you tried so far ? any code?

Answer (score 2):

If you have an instance of the child of the parent view in which you want to iterate through, you can follow this implementation.

You can search by `View` type, id, or tag.

```
//layout being the child of the view you have
View parent = layout.getParent();
for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View v = parent.getChildAt(i);

    //view type
    if (v instanceof ImageView) {
        //whatever
    } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
        //whatever
    } //

    //by tag
    if (v.getTag() instanceof yourObject) {//or == yourObject
        //whatever
    } else if (v.getTag() instanceof yourOtherObject) {//or == yourOtherObject
        //whatever
    } 

    //by id
     if (v.getId().equals(searchingForView.getId())) {
        //whatever
    } else if (v.getId().equals(searchingForOtherView.getId())) {
        //whatever
    } 


}
```

But if you knew the id, you could obviously do

```
View parent = layout.getParent();
View lookingForThisView = parent.findViewById(R.id.lookingforthisviewid);
```

Comment: @KeepCalm glad I could help, mark as answer if it indeed helped you out!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a parent for your view you can get your child's ID by calling `getIdentifier()` on your parent view. if you don't have you can get it's ID with :

```
getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("yourLayoutID","layout", getContext().getPackageName());
```

after that you if `getIdentifire()` returns `0` you the layout doesn't exists.

Answer (score 1):

```
  View parent = layout.getParent();    
  for(int i=0;i<parent.getChildCount();i++){
            View currentChild = parent.getChildAt(i);
            if(currentChild.getClass() == TextView.class) {
                Log.d("View Type", "TextView");
                Log.d("View Type", "TextView id:" + currentChild.getId());
            }

            if(currentChild.getClass() ==  ImageView.class) {
                Log.d("View Type", "ImageView");
                Log.d("View Type", "ImageView id:" + currentChild.getId());
            }
        }
```